# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) -Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, access-denied

I can not login to MySQL. I thought it was the wrong password and I tried to change the password..

It has no need to change the password. Because the **password is right**. The password is right, but I still can not login mysql. why? help me please, thanks. I've tried many methods.

```
    root@PC:/home/PC# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql
mysql stop/waiting
root@PC:/home/PC# pkill -9 mysql
root@PC:/home/PC# pkill -9 mysqld
root@PC:/home/PC# pkill -9 mysqld_safe
root@PC:/home/PC# ps -ef |grep mysql
root 27690 25962 0 19:51 pts/1 00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
root@PC:/home/PC# kill 27690
bash: kill: (27690) - No such process
root@PC:/home/PC# kill 25962
root@PC:/home/PC# ps uaxww | grep -i mysql
PC 24175 0.7 3.8 818760 156020 ? Sl 19:29 0:10 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox /media/DA94-D856/c/How to Recover_Reset forgotten MySQL root Password on Linux _ 2daygeek.htm
root 27695 0.0 0.0 13588 944 pts/1 S+ 19:52 0:00 grep --color=auto -i mysql
root@PC:/home/PC# kill 27695
bash: kill: (27695) - No such process
root@PC:/home/PC# kill 13588
bash: kill: (13588) - No such process
root@PC:/home/PC# sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 27701
root@PC:/home/PC# 160518 19:53:57 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time. Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
160518 19:53:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
160518 19:53:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
root@PC:/home/PC# mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("mypw") where User='root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newpw") where User='root';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3 Changed: 3 Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
root@PC:/home/PC# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql
root@PC:/home/PC# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
mysql start/running, process 28137
root@PC:/home/PC# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

(or dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5)

```
    PC@PC:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
[sudo] password for PC:
mysql stop/waiting
160513 7:09:38 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
mysql start/running, process 4046
PC@PC:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
PC@PC:~$ 
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("newpw") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Error log http://pastebin.com/HN2tGhJJ

etc/mysql/my.cf http://pastebin.com/cMSdGUei

**I tried it but it did not happen. root privileges may have been deleted.
use mysql;
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';**

```
[sudo] password for PC-2:
root@PC-2:/home/PC-2# mysql -u root -pFalanca_mypw
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@PC-2:/home/PC-2# grep password /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
password = vwSY1PE7GgDRUbB7
password = vwSY1PE7GgDRUbB7
root@PC-2:/home/PC-2# mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 71
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  https://www.ozgurbilgi.net
```

Comment: User debian-sys-maint has permission to grant permission to user

Comment: How can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the config (.cnf) file of MySql, set the following property,

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

The default value is 127.0.0.1. Change it to 0.0.0.0 and you will be able to access it. Otheriwse, it only allows through the localhost through ssh.

Comment: So, how can we solve it in another way? I need to connect to 127.0.0.1. there is script on the server. I do not have problems before with 127.0.0.1 Thanks.

Comment: I have provided a solution to this problem in C#. It is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603982/connection-to-mysql-from-net-using-ssh-net-library/36517176#36517176).

Comment: We do not use ssh. The server physically here.. This private server. thanks

Comment: bind-address = 0.0.0.0

I tried but it did not work. please help me more?