# How to perform "double hop" via SFTP/SSH in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, winscp

In my scenario i am trying to go from `Local App Server -> Middle Server (DMZ) -> Client Server`

I need to move files from the `Local App Server` to the `Client Server` and back.

**So my question is what is the most widely used standard for doing this?**

I am currently using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp) to connect to the `Middle Server` via SFTP, and then invoking a command on the `Middle Server` to download and upload files to the `Client Server`. I'm not really a fan of this, as i feel like its prone to error as i am manually entering a command, rather than using the WinSCP's library to upload and download. It also leaves me stuck when i try to list all files on the `Client Server` with a command, as the function returns `void`

I have looked at [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) which seems like its more widely used, however i cant see any real way of performing a "double hop" with that library either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), it's easy:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...=",
};

sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Tunnel", "on");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelHostName", "tunnel.example.com");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelUserName", "username");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelPasswordPlain", "password");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelHostKey", "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...=");

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Your code
}
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a code template to connect through tunnel](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code), like the one above, for you (except for the `TunnelHostKey`).

---

With SSH.NET you can implement a port forwarding explicitly by:

- opening connection to the "Middle Server";
- creating a forwarded port;
- opening a second connection to the forwarded port.

For some example, see [Connection to MySQL from .NET using SSH.NET Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32603982/850848).

---

Another hackish solution is to execute `ssh` on the "Middle Server" to facilitate the second "hop".