# How to send command to Telnet over SSH connection

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, telnet, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET library to connect to a remote server and then initiate a Telnet session. I am able to do that using `SshClient` class. My problem is that now I am not able to send commands to that Telnet connection using the connected SSH client. The `RunCommand` method sends the command to the server instead to the Telnet session. How can I achieve that.

Thank you,
Usman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSH.NET to forward a localport to the remote Telnet server through the SSH connection.

And then use some [C# Telnet library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/390188/850848). to connect to the local forwarded port.

You can start with this question:
[Connection to MySQL from .NET using SSH.NET Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32603982/850848)
Just replace the `MySqlConnection` with your Telnet client class.